# How to load Mongo data (Complex data) into pyspark data frame?

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark

I am fairly new to Spark and I am trying to load data from MongoDB to dataframe using

```py
sqlContext.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource")
.option("uri",uri)
.option("database",db)
.option("collection",ct)
.load()
```

, but having some difficulties.

Problem is Spark is inferring the schema of the collection, but fails to load the data saying "cannot cast DOCUMENT in to `ArrayType(StringType,true....`

The problem occurs when I try to enforce the schema of the mongo objects as it is. If I load the complex type fields (ex: `StructType(List(StructFiled(...))))` as 
`StringType()` then it loads fine. But then I will have to parse those fields later, load as JSON and then split into columns.

```
Actual Mongo schema = 

StructType(List(
StructField(_id,StructType(List(StructField(oid,StringType,true))),true),
StructField(_meta,StructType(List(StructField(ind,StringType,true),
StructField(updt,StringType,true),
StructField(clid,StringType,true),
StructField(ddr,StringType,true))),true),
StructField(cd,ArrayType(StructType(List(StructField(cn,StringType,true),StructField(rs,StringType,true),StructField(ck,ArrayType(StringType,true),true))),true),true),
StructField(date,TimestampType,true),
StructField(mid,StringType,true),
StructField(lm,ArrayType(StructType(List(StructField(code,StringType,true),StructField(ed,StringType,true),StructField(lid,StringType,true),StructField(lk,StringType,true),StructField(status,StringType,true),StructField(type,StringType,true),StructField(pn,StringType,true),StructField(pv,StringType,true),StructField(nk,StringType,true),StructField(id,StringType,true),StructField(dt,StringType,true),StructField(mi,StringType,true))),true),true),
StructField(expo,ArrayType(StructType(List(StructField(ek,StringType,true),StructField(ev,ArrayType(StructType(List(StructField(en,StringType,true),StructField(ev,StringType,true))),true),true))),true),true),
StructField(pim,StringType,true),
StructField(pis,StringType,true),
StructField(piv,StringType,true),
StructField(pvw,StringType,true)))
```

**The above schema I want to flatten it and put every field into a column.**

Any suggestions for:

1. is there a better way to load it instead of loading as a string?
2. if NOT, then how what is the best way of flattening the complex StringType values in to columns?

Comment: have you found a solution?